# Android T:V Background customisation

Tags: android, sdk, android-support-library, android-tv, leanback

I have five background images which are displayed back to back after a certain time interval. I have to add a page indicator for backgrounds so that user can know which background is currently selected. The user should also be able to select next backgrounds using tv remote.

I cannot compromise tv look and feel for rail and its contents which are displayed on the screen.

I also need to resize background image. I do not want the image to be full screen and its size should cover half portion of tv only. Background image should overlap first rails content to an extent.

I am not getting any such sample or blogs depicting customization of background. Any help would be really appreciated..!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try to [use layout themes for TV](https://developer.android.com/training/tv/start/layouts.html#themes).

> Android [Themes](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html) can provide a basis for layouts in your TV apps.
>   You should use a theme to modify the display of your app activities
>   that are meant to run on a TV device. This section explains which
>   themes you should use.

Style and Themes can be:

> A style is a collection of attributes that specify the look and format
>   for a View or window. A style can specify attributes such as height,
>   padding, font color, font size, background color, and much more. A
>   style is defined in an XML resource that is separate from the XML that
>   specifies the layout.

You can see samples codes as well from the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/tv/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

I added two fragments inside my Activity. One fragment is for displaying background and indicator. While another fragment is extending BrowseFragment of leanback library, and is used to display rails/headers as is depicted in tv app android sample which is generated via android studio.